# Promise all map update array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I'm using bluebird and mongoose, I'm getting an array of users in a previous function. I want to update `users` to set the property `hasCar` true or false for each user from my array.

```
function findCars(users) {
  return Promise.all(users.map((user) => {
    return Car.count({
      _creator: new ObjectId(req.user),
      userId: user._id
    })
    .then((car) => {
      user.hasCar = !!car;
      return user;
    });
  }))
  .then(console.log);
}
```

The problem is, in the console.log those users don't have the property `hasCar` set. I tried different ways with no success.

Comment: Instead of `users[index].hasCar = ...`, why not simply use `user.hasCar = ...`?

Comment: And instead of `if (car) { … = true; } else { … = false; }` why not simply use `… = Boolean(car);`?

Comment: Hey thanks Phil for your answer, I also tried that way before and also `return user` after the `else`, does not work, I still get the old user.

Comment: What exactly does "*the array does not want to be updated*" mean? How do you test the array for updates? Please show us that code that is not working, not only the code that you suspect to be the issue. Pretty surely you just aren't waiting for the updates.

Comment: You mean the db is not being updated?

Comment: I updated the example for better explanation. No I don't want to update the db

Comment: Why the `new` for `Promise.all`?  I'm not even sure what that would mean.

Comment: You could clean up your `if-else` block with `user.hasCar = !!car;` if that style doesn't offend your sensibilities.

Comment: @scott-sauyet I'm not sure but I think the new is optionnal, it should works with or without

Comment: @John, I would suggest removing it.  I don't think it will fix your problem, but it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Please post your solution [as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not an edit to your question

Answer (score 1):

Found what was wrong, it seems you can't add a property which does not exist in my mongoose model `User`. To bypass it I did:

```
let updatedUser = user.toObject();
updatedUser.hasCar = !!car;
return updatedUser;
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: We can use lean() with Mongoose query to modify the result https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html#when-to-use-lean

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as it is.  I made some simple changes to fake out `Car.count` and removed `ObjectId`, and it works as expected:

```
const cars = {1: ['car a', 'car b'], 3: ['car c']};

const Car = {
  count: (user) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
                       setTimeout(() => resolve(cars[user.userId]), 1000))
};

function findCars(users) {
  return Promise.all(users.map((user) => 
    Car.count({
      userId: user._id
    })
    .then((car) => {
      user.hasCar = !!car;
      return user;
    })
  ))
  .then(console.log);
}

const users = [{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 3}];

findCars(users);
```

This returns a Promise, and one second later logs the following to the console:

```
[{"_id":1,"hasCar":true},{"_id":2,"hasCar":false},{"_id":3,"hasCar":true}]
```

Note, I originally used the simpler

```
count: (user) => Promise.resolve(cars[user.userId])
```

But I wanted to ensure some true async.  Neither way had any issues.

You can see this in action on **[RunKit](https://runkit.com/crosseye/58ae2a961458360014f939e8)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott for your time, it was driving me crazy, I finally found the culprit, it was my mongoose, I edited my post.

Comment: @John: Glad you found it.  Did you do something like my test here or did you run it through a debugger?